# Can I stream a Excel file row by row to the HttpRequest output stream?

Tags: java, spring

I am using the class org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSWorkbook to generate a report in Excel format that is later downloaded. This class creates a temporary file to manipulate and once done I am sending the final file to the output stream of my HttpResponse.

Can I stream the rows of the Excel file while they are being created directly to the outpuststream of the HttpResponse? In other works avoiding the creation of the temporary file?

The files are huge, so doing it all in memory is also not an option.

Comment: You very well could, but it will likely also load that entire data into memory in order to send the request. If that's acceptable, then by all means.

Comment: Thanks, just edited the question, in memory is not an option.

Comment: In my mind, your current solution sounds feasible to me. I don't see any major advantage to be gained by changing how you're sending that data - you'll end up basically re-implementing file downloading on the front-end side, and streaming data to it using your service instead of letting apache do the file transfer. There's certainly ways to do this (websockets come to mind), but again I don't see any good reason to do so.

Comment: If you already have working code, this wouldn't take long to test.  Have you tried it?

Comment: @Rogue the advantage is that I don't use server disk space, whch is currently a problem. I cannot generate the Excel in the client side eighter if that is what you are suggesting as per the client runs out of memory. My ideal scenario is o stream the bytes that describe the opening of the file, stream the data dynamically as soon as it is read from the database, not keeping it in memory for long and in small chunks and once done with the data send the bytes that close the file making it a valid xls file to be opened by the client.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot do that. Why not? Because `.xls` and `.xlsx` formats are not streamable. The former is a binary format, the latter is a compressed ZIP archive of XML and binary files.

Answer (score 0):

Excel file is a binary file and when you read/write its content you can not distinguish a row (where it starts or ends). So, no you can not send it row by row as you never tell how to split the file into separate rows. The only option is that you work with data that being written to excel and transfer data in textual format and on the receiving side the information will be written into excel. But I don't believe that that's what you want, as it looks like it is responsibility of your logic to create excel file. Once you have an excel file it is just a binary info that can not be analyzed. You can send it as a whole only